# Find counts of duplicates in list of sets

Tags: python, list, set

Hi i have to check the overlapping and duplicate of string from the data , i could do it can anyone help me to find the duplicate of string .I have this data `s = [(100, 350,"a"), (125, 145,"a"), (200, 400, "d"), (0, 10, "a")]` and i done the overlap part but theduplicate check odf string i need help .

```
def overlap(a, b) -> bool:
  a_start, a_end, _ = a
  b_start, b_end, _ = b
  return a_start < b_end and b_start < a_end
ls = [(100, 350,"a"), (125, 145,"a"), (200, 400, "d"), (0, 10, "a")]
overlaps = set()
for idx_a in range(len(ls)):
    for idx_b in range(len(ls)):
        if idx_a != idx_b:  
            if overlap(ls[idx_a], ls[idx_b]):
                overlaps.add(ls[idx_a])
                overlaps.add(ls[idx_b])

print(f"Number of overlaps: {len(overlaps)}")
```

Comment: i explained every thing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to use set in case you need only number of overlaps.

I would solve your problem like this:

```
def is_overlapped(a, b) -> bool:  # changed the name for readability
    a_start, a_end, _ = a
    b_start, b_end, _ = b
    return a_start < b_end and b_start < a_end
ls = [(100, 350,"a"), (125, 145,"a"), (200, 400, "d"), (0, 10, "a")]
overlaps = 0 # int instead of set
for idx_a, value_a in enumerate(ls):  # this is more pythonic way to access the index and item at the same time
    for idx_b, value_b in enumerate(ls):
        if idx_a != idx_b:
            if is_overlapped(value_a, value_b):
                overlaps += 1
print(f"Number of overlaps: {overlaps}")
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working